# Wpf: Remove item from listbox using button (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a class `VM_Subgroup` that contains an `ObservableCollection<VM_Subgroup> RequiredSubgroups`. I am using [WPF.DragDrop][1] to enable dragging VM_Subgroups from a TreeView to a ListBox bound to `RequiredSubgroups`, as shown here: https://i.imgur.com/A1qV0By.gif

However, I have no idea how to bind the "Remove" button. Ordinarily I would make a shell class as follows (pseudocode):

```
public class RemovableSubgroup(ObservableCollection<RemovableSubgroup> parentCollection, VM_subgroup subgroup)
this.Subgroup = subgroup;
this.ParentCollection = parentCollection
...
DeleteMe = new RelayCommand(execute: _=> this.ParentCollection.Remove(this));
```

and bind the Remove button the "DeleteMe" command. However, I can't do that here because WPF.DragDrop requires the source and destination collections to be of the same type. Barring that, I'm not sure how to bind the button. I tried using [this solution][2] (substituting RelayCommand for ActionCommand because I'm already using other RelayCommands), but the Remove button does nothing:

```
public VM_Subgroup()
{
...
DeleteRequiredSubgroup = new SynthEBD.RelayCommand(
                canExecute: _ => true,
                execute: x => this.requiredSubgroups.Remove((VM_Subgroup)x)
                );
}
```

xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="lbRequiredSubgroups" Grid.Row="15" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding requiredSubgroups}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" MinHeight="30" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#5844b4">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Width="75" Height="20" Margin="15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Command="{Binding DeleteRequiredSubgroup}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Remove</Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I've also tried a CodeBehind solution similar to [this one][3], but whenever I try to edit the listbox contents instead of the ObservableCollection that it's bound to I get an [Operation is not valid][3] error.

I'd really appreciate a tip on how to go about this!

```
  [1]: https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop
  [2]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967554/how-to-add-a-remove-button-to-each-item-of-a-listbox-and-implement-its-functio
  [3]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089104/operation-is-not-valid-while-itemssource-is-in-use-access-and-modify-elements-w
```

Comment: I'm not clear crom your description what the datacontext of your listbox is. I guess it's the instance of vm subgroup that has those subgroups. If so. Use relativesource binding from the button to a command in vmsubgroup. Pass the datacontext if the button as the command parameter. You can then .remove that instance from subgroups.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! For reference in case anyone stumbles on this, the RelayCommand remained unchanged and the xaml binding for the button became:

```
<Button Width="75" Height="20" Margin="15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.DeleteRequiredSubgroup}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">Remove</Button>
```

Much appreciated! Do I need to mark your answer as resolved? I don't see the button for it.

Comment: I wrote a comment rather than answer. Because I was guessing on what you had.